# Adopt a tag for someone else

Tags: feature-request, unicoins

I am a very loving brother. I am such a nice person that I want to adopt another tag for my twin brother and am willing to spend my precious unicoins for that. So because I am a loving brother I would like to see his avatar next to the `bug` tag. I chose this one because there was not `defect` tag... aaaa I mean because he loves bugs so much. So can I adopt the tag for him? Please :)

Answer (score 1):

I have already used all of my Unicorns to sponsor the `Defect` on behalf of my X.

`Bug` and `Pest` tags have been reserved siblings and most children under the age of 3.

Comment: +1, just because of that big capital "X" at the end. Make it bigger....

Comment: All X's can be added to this tag.

Comment: That is so kind of you, please take my unicoins also, and put an adv. for this tag on side bar of every SE site.

Answer (score 0):

Yup, all yours.

However, because this is not a standard unicoin purchase, it will cost two kidneys and a spleen. If you don't like that, then you should just stick with one tag.

Comment: No problemo my brother has all that - take them